# Android . Where to save downloaded images?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

In my application I have several images in drawable folder. That makes apk big. Now I have uploaded them in my Google drive and when the user will connect to the internet it will download that images from drive. Where to save that downloaded images? in external storage , in database or in other place? I want that the user couldn't delete that images.

Comment: it's depends on how you can download image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store them in Internal phone memory.

To save the images

```
private String saveToInternalSorage(Bitmap bitmapImage){
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
         // path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir
        File directory = cw.getDir("youDirName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // Create imageDir
        File mypath=new File(directory,"img.jpg");

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {           

            fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);

       // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
            bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return directory.getAbsolutePath();
    }
```

To access the stored file

```
private void loadImageFromStorage(String path)
{

    try {
        File f = new File(path, "img.jpg");
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f));
        // here is the retrieved image in b
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

You can save files directly on the device's internal storage. By default, files saved to the internal storage are private to your application and other applications cannot access them (nor can the user). When the user uninstalls your application, these files are removed.

For more information [Internal Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)

Comment: but how much storage I have there?

Comment: Device manufacturers can impose quite restrictive limits, perhaps as low as 100MB shared among all applications. I would suggest you to google about it. You can also get to know the free internal space available programmtically

Comment: I shall put there only 5-7 mb

Comment: Then I don't think you will face any problem. I guess all cell phone users will have at least 500mb free space.

Answer (score 2):

> I want that the user couldn't delete that images

You can't really do that. Images weren't here unless user selected them so why you do not want to let user delete them? in such case you will download it again or ask user to select. normal "cache" scenario. Not to mention you are in fact unable to protect these images  as user can always clear app data (including databases and internal storage).

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vahe_muradyan.yourquote      here is my app . look there is defaults button and when you click on it  it will open default activity

Comment: shall I let the user to delete those images?

Comment: Yes. You cannot prevent them from doing so anyway.